# Raw binary file generated by objcopy is too big

Tags: c, gcc, linker, binary, mips

Already read this but cannot solve my problem.

[huge binary files with objcopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235009/huge-binary-files-with-objcopy)

For some testing need.
I have to add following link script when link.

```
.section_test 0x11323000: {  *(.section_test) }
```

This self-defined section must start at a big address 0x11323000.

Then use objcopymips to generate the raw binary file

```
objcopymips -O binary vxWorks.st E0122.bin
```

This step makes the final raw binary file,the bin file, too big. from 27MB to more than 270MB.

In this way it cannot be loaded in our machine which only have around 64MB physical memory.

Can I reduce the size of it without remove any sections and still let it be executable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`objcopy -O binary` produces the memory image of the program, based on the load address of sections. In your case, the load and the runtime address of `.section_test` are the same, i.e. the load address is `0x11323000` which explains the big file size.

The usual solution is to create an executable with compact load image and have the program itself copy the necessary parts from their load address to their runtime address before they are used.

Example:

```
.section_test 0x11323000 : AT(some-small-address) {  *(.section_test) }
```

or

```
.section_test 0x11323000 : {  *(.section_test) } AT> some-region-name
```

Check this page as well:
https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Output-Section-LMA.html#Output-Section-LMA

Comment: perfect answer, thanks a lot! I've check this manual before but missed this part....

Comment: I understand the answer, but why bss section is not included in the big file ? (in the example in the above link) - bss section has no "AT"